# How to allow users to tag other users?

Tags: android

I am trying to allow users to tag multiple users and trying to figure out how to go about it?

I have thought of the following options:

Option 1:
-listview that pops up as a user types in text with matching results

cons: have to constantly search the server for matching users in the followers/following array

Option 2:
-use usernames without pop up and have users have to include the exact correct username spelling with the ability to look at following/followers on same page

cons: user has to make sure they type the exact correct username and no suggestions

Option 3:
-users press a choose button that takes them to their followers/following list and clicking on a username adds that user

cons: user does not have the ability to search for a name

Option 4:
-same as 3 but with a search in the followers/following list that will end up searching the server if not all the followers and following have been stored locally

cons: hitting server for searches constantly

Comment: Why did you mention `android` tag? You question is about UX/UI.

Comment: Well I am using android and trying to figure out if android offers something for this or what is most efficient for an android app

Answer (score 0):

I would go for Option 1. You can retrieve only the first few results of your query; if desired username is not in the list, then the user is going to type another letter. I'd say that a single tag would be finalized in 2-4 letters.

That doesn't seem so hard to me for servers to stand, and is the *best* option for the user. It is, as a user, what I would like to have.

The only alternative seems to me Option 5. asynchronously retrieve all following/followers from server, and meanwhile let the user search through this local list.